# Is there a function for selecting the first 2 words after a specified string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to select the first 2 words after the string 'POS PURCHASE' in my data set.

This is my data set.

```
df:   
    ID        transaction_description
     1         POS PURCHASE MR PRICE WHK FAC
     2         WITHDRAWAL FEE
     3         POS PURCHASE KFC WERNHIL STATE
     4         REJECTED ATM TRANSACTION
     5         ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL
     6         POS PURCHASE EDGARS GROVE
```

This is how i want my output to look like:

```
dfnew:
    ID       transaction_description                 TRANX
     1       POS PURCHASE MR PRICE WHK FAC          MR PRICE
     2       WITHDRAWAL FEE                         WITHDRAWAL FEE
     3       POS PURCHASE KFC WERNHIL STATE         KFC WERNHIL
     4    REJECTED ATM TRANSACTION               REJECTED ATM TRANSACTION
     5         ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL                   ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL  
     6         POS PURCHASE EDGARS GROVE MALL        EDGARS GROVE
```

I tried using this code but I'm not able to create a new column that contains the output I want.

```
code:

   for value in df['transaction_description'].values:
       non_data = re.split('POS PURCHASE |POS PURCHASE ',value)
       terms_list = [term for term in non_data if len(term) > 0] 
       substrs = [term.split()[0:1] for term in terms_list] 
       result = [' '.join(term) for term in substrs] 
   print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"transaction_description": ['POS PURCHASE MR PRICE WHK FAC', 'WITHDRAWAL FEE', 'POS PURCHASE KFC WERNHIL STATE', 'REJECTED ATM TRANSACTION', 'ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL', 'POS PURCHASE EDGARS GROVE']})
df["TRANX"] = df["transaction_description"].apply(lambda x: re.search(r"POS PURCHASE (\w+\s+\w+)", x).group(1) if "POS PURCHASE" in x else x)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
          transaction_description                     TRANX
0   POS PURCHASE MR PRICE WHK FAC                  MR PRICE
1                  WITHDRAWAL FEE            WITHDRAWAL FEE
2  POS PURCHASE KFC WERNHIL STATE               KFC WERNHIL
3        REJECTED ATM TRANSACTION  REJECTED ATM TRANSACTION
4             ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL       ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL
5       POS PURCHASE EDGARS GROVE              EDGARS GROVE
```

---

Edit -- using `str.extract`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"transaction_description": ['POS PURCHASE MR PRICE WHK FAC', 'WITHDRAWAL FEE', 'POS PURCHASE KFC WERNHIL STATE', 'REJECTED ATM TRANSACTION', 'ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL', 'POS PURCHASE EDGARS GROVE']})
df["TRANX"] = df["transaction_description"].str.extract(r"POS PURCHASE (\w+\s+\w+)")
df["TRANX"].fillna(df["transaction_description"], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: Im getting an error when running your code....       "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"

Comment: Looks like there are some rows with no data after `POS PURCHASE`

Answer (score 0):

If POS PURCHASE is always at the beginning, as is the case in your sample data, you can just remove it.

```
df['TRANX'] = df['transaction_description'].str.replace('POS PURCHASE ', '')
```